# Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'User.User' in django

Tags: python, authentication, django-forms, django-registration

I was trying to create registration form but once I saved then I was getting mentioned error i.e.
**'Manager isn't available 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'User.User''**. I went through some solutions as well provided over the Internet even then I couldn't able to apply the required solution as I'm novice in coding world.

I'm sharing my code so kindly go through with that and provide your valuable input.

> setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'User',
        'account',     
    ]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'User.User'
```

> User/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, UserManager)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def documents(self):
        return self.document_uploaded.all()

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = None
        if self.first_name or self.last_name:
            full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        elif self.username:
            full_name = self.username
        else:
            full_name = self.email
        return full_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

> User/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView
from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView, TemplateView, View, DeleteView)
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import ( PasswordResetEmailForm, LoginForm)
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, AccessMixin

User = get_user_model()

class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["ENABLE_GOOGLE_LOGIN"] = settings.ENABLE_GOOGLE_LOGIN
        context["GP_CLIENT_SECRET"] = settings.GP_CLIENT_SECRET
        context["GP_CLIENT_ID"] = settings.GP_CLIENT_ID
        return context

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)       


class LogoutView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        request.session.flush()
        return redirect("User:user_login")


@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def forgot_password(request):
    return render(request, 'forgot_password.html')

class PasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_form.html'
    form_class = PasswordResetEmailForm
    email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
```

> account/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from User.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, UserManager)

User = get_user_model()
```

> account/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime as dt 
from User.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def registerView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login_url')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request,'registration/register.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'User.User'` to `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Thanks for your input. When I applied mentioned solution I getting below error.  "Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups' .."